# ng-bind : concatenate 2 values where one of them is conditional

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am able to concatenate two values inside ng-bind by using '+'. However, the 2nd value depends on a condition.

How can I hide/show this value using **ng-if** or **ng-switch**. I tried using ng-if but it ate the ng-bind (ie. interpolated values don't show at all. Maybe **ng-if** has greater priority as **ng-bind** has priority 0.  eg.

`<a ng-bind="(document.name) + (vm.showifConditionTrue)"></a>`

Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: show some code, what you have tried so far?

Comment: Have you tried something like ng-bind a function and filter the result there?

Comment: Did you try ng-show?

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
<a ng-bind="(document.name) + (vm.showifConditionTrue ? 'what to show if true' : 'what to show if false')"></a>
```

if you don't want anything to show when false just use

```
<a ng-bind="(document.name) + (vm.showifConditionTrue ? 'what to show if true' : '')"></a>
```